# Could an array of word vectors be handled if use imbalanced data techniques?

Tags: python, arrays, word2vec, text-classification, imbalanced-data

I have an imbalanced classification dataset of text and I used word vectors (word2vec) to embed the text. So, the result of word vector is an array. The next condition, I have **variable X for word vector's array** and **variable Y for class/target of word vectors**. If I use technique to handle imbalanced classification dataset, could an array of word vectors be handled too? Or added data / dropped data with imbalanced data technique make a wrong array? Because the technique for handle imbalanced dataset just add/drop data based on label/target of word vector's array.

I have tried and that problems don't get any error but my accuracy of models can't show the best one. I don't know it has a relation or not.

Can anyone help me for the explanation?

Comment: Please ask non-programming questions like this one on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. In general it's not recommended to apply any resampling technique with text data, you should probably keep the original data proportions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.